# Ajax уведомление о подписке

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

Cделал уведомление о подписке, но не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы менялось содержимое уведомления. Кто-то может помочь в данном вопросе?

Скрипт на JS:

```js
$('a.button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('{% url "user_follow" %}', {
      id: $(this).data('id'),
      action: $(this).data('action')
    },
    function(data) {
      if (data['status'] == 'ok') {
        var previous_action = $('a.button').data('action');

        // toggle data-action
        $('a.button').data('action',
          previous_action == 'follow' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow');
        // toggle link text
        $('a.button').text(
          previous_action == 'follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');

        // update total followers
        var previous_followers = parseInt(
          $('span.count .total').text());
        $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'follow' ? previous_followers + 1 : previous_followers - 1);
      }
    }
  );
});

// добавляем в DOM контейнер для сообщений
if (!document.querySelector('.messages')) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.classList.add('messages');
  container.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 15px; right: 15px; width: 250px;';
  document.body.appendChild(container);
}

// получаем контейнер
const messages = document.querySelector('.messages');

// при нажатию на кнопку добавляем в контейнер alert
if ($('a.button').data('action')) {
  document.querySelector('[data-create="message"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const messageText = 'Follow {{ user.username }}';
    const message = document.createElement('div');
    message.className = 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show';
    message.innerHTML = `${messageText}<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>`;
    messages.appendChild(message);
  });
} else if ($('a.button').data('action') != 'follow') {
  document.querySelector('[data-create="message"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const messageText = 'Unfollow {{ user.username }}';
    const message = document.createElement('div');
    message.className = 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show';
    message.innerHTML = `${messageText}<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>`;
    messages.appendChild(message);
  });
}
```

Comment: Уточните, что именно вам надо поменять и где?

Comment: подключите jquery через cdn к примеру

Comment: При клике на кнопку подписаться, всплывает уведомление "Подписались на юзера", при обратном действии тоже самое уведомление. А должно по задумке "Вы отписались от юзера". Не срабатывает блок else if

Comment: jQuery подключен в базовом шаблоне.